# All I want to do is share 2 folders

Tags: networking, server, samba

... on my home network.

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an SSD, created the 2 folders on an HDD in the Ubuntu machine, clicked the 'tab' on the local network share for each folder.

One folder I want anybody on our home network to access, so I've 'ticked' "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder" and "Guest access" then changed the permissions tab to Owner, Group, and Others to "Create and delete files".

The other folder I wish to have only accessible to me, so I've shared that then changed the permissions tab to Owner, Group to "Create and delete files", but Others have "None".

On the Windows machine I add the network drive \ip-address\folder name for each folder. I was unable to access the first (supposedly open!) folder until I added the line "force user = myUbuntuID" under the global section of /etc/samba/smb.conf

That has now enabled access from the Windows machine.

I remain unable to access the second folder. On the Windows machine I add the network drive \ip-address\folder, I get user/password prompt and enter my Ubuntu ID and password, but it just says "Access is denied".

Answer (score 1):

> On the Windows machine I add the network drive \ip-address\folder, I
>   get user/password prompt and enter my Ubuntu ID and password, but it
>   just says "Access is denied".

There are two passwords on a machine acting as a Linux Samba server. One is the local login name and its associated password that you use to log into the operating system itself.

The other is the samba password for that local login user that you use across the network. You need to add yourself to the samba password database with this command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a myUbuntuID
```